# How to restore and use my Yashica 35 G?

Tags: 35mm, old-cameras, restoration, yashica

I have recently acquired a Yashica 35G, originally because I just thought it was pretty. Now that I've given it a good inspection though, I'm wondering if it might be usable. The mechanism checks out fine, and the only visible problem is corrosion on the battery contacts. I've read the basic info I could find on Google and it seems to suggest if I can fix that, I might be able to use this camera? So, look at the photos and let me know how you might fix the corrosion and get this baby working again? Is it possible? I only paid $20 and like I said, it is pretty, so if I can't fix it that's ok.

[image: Front View]
[image: Inside]
[image: Corrosion]

Comment: You can normally clean battery contacts by wiping them with a lubricant or using something sharp to take away the corroded metal. If worse case scenario the battery contacts are completely a destroyed you might be able to find spare parts on the Internet, eBay etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the Yashica 35 series cameras are quite nice and I think it's worthwhile trying to get your camera working again.

Regarding your specific question, you can find helpful advice regarding battery corrosion in this camera [here](http://www.yashica-guy.com/document/repair.html#one), summary: Use cotton swaps lightly moistened with white vinegar and lots of patience to clean out the corrosion, some pieces of paper and toothpicks will help with tricky spots.

After you have cleaned the battery compartment, generally, the only way of figuring out whether the camera works as it should is to put a roll of film in it and start shooting. In order to do so, it's probably best to carefully read the manual first, which you should be able to easily find on the internet, for example [here](http://www.yashica-guy.com/document/manual.pdf) or [the 35 without the G should be quite similar](http://www.butkus.org/chinon/yashica/yashica_electro_35/yashica_electro_35.htm).

One problem you might encounter is that the required batteries are not available anymore, however you will also find advice on replacements readily available with a quick Google search, for example you can use [an adapter](http://www.yashica-guy.com/document/battery.html), but there are also more self-made versions. I think there are also modern alkali replacements for the PX32 with a slightly higher voltage, which shouldn't be a big problem in this case (but I can't vouch for it, as I don't have any first-hand experience with this camera).

As your camera seems to be in generally good condition, I would be hopeful that things work out fine. However, on a final note, another common problem with the Yashica 35 series is the "[pad of death](http://elekm.net/pages/cameras/repair_pad_of_death.htm)", which requires a slightly more elaborate repair (Google helps again).

[This overview](http://www.yashica-guy.com/document/chrono.html) of the different models of the Yashica 35 series might also be interesting.

Comment: One additional comment: Be very careful when cleaning the battery contact spring, as they are quite brittle after being exposed to battery acid and often snap when you try to clean them.

Comment: I had found some of that information on Google and I'm pretty handy with electronical stuff, so I'll give it a go! Thanks!